# Random "IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Review your information."

Tags: paypal-ipn

I'm working on Paypal integration with IPN. To make it easy, I'm using the IPN Simulator. It worked few times, and now it never work again. I've tried some other DNS, and it work (sometimes). The returned message is something, well... mysterious !

**IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Review your information.**

I've searching the doc, and there is nothing about this message : no explanation, no advice, nothing... Information seems to be ok, and agin, it worked few times and now, it never work again : why ? How is it possible ? Is the paypal service blocked somewhere ?

My DNS : "lecomite.eu"

The right calling URL is "lecomite.eu/services/paypal/". All other goes to 500.

**EDIT :**

Ok, this is an error I've made. I apologize. But please, Paypal team, produce message a lot more informative about what's append. It should be more helpful than this undocumented **IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Review your information.** that don't tell anything about the transactions made, not made, send, not send, and where is the bad thing.

NOTE : I've read your "job opportunity in the HTTP response frame" - i'm developing my own high performance web server, so I've read it.

Comment: have you check if POST method in your website returns 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: The right calling URL is "lecomite.eu/services/paypal/" : this is the only path that do not return 500. It work few times, and now the message seems to say "ok, I'll never send anymore to this IPN at this URL...".

Perhaps I'm wrong. I will check the real response...

Comment: It seems your URL are invalid thus the IPN could not be send. You can try out using IPN Simulator at PayPal developer portal.

Answer (score 1):

This error is most often caused by omitting the "https:" at the beginning.

The Sandbox IPN Simulator should be revised to give some hint that the IPN URI **must** start with **https:**. Starting with "http:" or "www" will always fail with no good error message. I wish I could rewrite the simulator a bit.

Sorry it took two years for me to post this simple answer. Of course, your problem may have been a different one. But you're right: the error message is horrible.